# Want to do Two diffrent activity in same screen

Tags: android

I want to do two different activity in same screen . I know about fragment but when we use fragment it show different UI for 10 inch table and different for 4.6 inch mobile. But i want that my screen always open by dividing screen in two equal part in landscape mode  and i can able to do different activity in both equally divided part of screen. I searched a lot but didn't find any appropriate solution for my question.

Actually i want that to develop a game in one half of screen for User and another half for computer(Android Os).

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @2Dee.. Do you read my question..?

Comment: Yes, I saw your question doesn't provide enough information to even start giving you constructive solutions, so I stated the obvious. It is impossible to have 2 Activities on screen at the same time, so you should use fragments and layouts scaling to different screens or different layouts to support different screen sizes. But you knew that already since you have read the official documentation, right ?

Comment: You have clearly demonstrated that you don't know how Android works, at the most basic level. I'd suggest **actually reading** the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing in equal parts can be achieved by weight attribute.

I am assuming that you are well versed with fragments so I am just telling you the xml part by which your screen will be divided into two equal fragments.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.Fragment1"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp" />

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
          android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

This will divide your screen into two parts and about the different UI in different fragments.

You can inflate a single xml file into multiple fragment classes hence achieving the same UI

Comment: Thanks fro reply....Is it work for same as in 10 inch and 4.6 inch android device.?

Comment: He want to use TWO activitys in his app, it's impossible

Comment: @ThanhLe That is why I am telling him the Fragments Approach

Comment: @BlueGreen yes it will work but with the fragments approach. you cant have only one activity in the foreground

Comment: @BlueGreen: If you think you require two activities, I would suggest you rethink your design. For that purpose you need to use Fragment, that was what it was designed for. The screen estate on mobile devices is already limited, hence, the design choice not to support multiple activities sharing the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Android `Activities` are not designed to be displayed two at a time. One `Activity` - one application screen. If you want to achieve what you have described then use `Fragment`s and Android layout system that allows to have separate layouts for different screen size devices using `smallestWidth` attributes. Check out this [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers) article. Android has a very powerful resources (layouts, dimensions, etc) management system, use it.